# Irreducibility of a certain polynomial associated to an irreducible representation of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $k$ be an agebraically closed field of characteristic 0.
Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$.
A representation of $G$ is a homomorphism $\psi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ where $GL(V)$ is the general linear group of a finite dsimensional vector space $V$ over $k$, i.e. the group of $k$-linear automorphisms of $V$.
This is equivalent to giving a $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[G] \rightarrow End_k(V)$ where $k[G]$ is the group algebra over $k$ and $End_k(V)$ is the $k$-algebra of $k$-linear endomorphisms of $V$. By abuse of notation, we use the same letter $\psi$ for this homomorphism.

Every element $\alpha \in k[G]$ can be uniquely written as $\sum_i a_i\sigma_i$ where $a_i\in k, i = 1, \dots, n$ and $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ are the distinct elements of $G$. Since $k$ is an infinite field, there exists a unique polynomial $P\in k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ such that $P(a_1,\dots,a_n) = det(\psi(\alpha))$.
$P$ is called the norm polynomial of $\psi$ and denoted as $P_\psi$.
It is clear that $P_\psi = P_{\psi_1}P_{\psi_2}$ where $\psi$ is the direct sum of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.

> Is $P_\psi$ is irreducible if $\psi$ is irreducible?

The motivation is as follows.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of a finite Galois extension $K/F$.
One of the proofs of the normal basis theorem uses the polynomial $det(x_{\sigma_i\sigma_j^{-1}})$ where we assign a variable $x_i$ to each $\sigma_i$ and we write $x_{\sigma_i}$ for $x_i$.

I was thinking about the meaning of this polynomial and found it out.
Let $\psi: k[G] \rightarrow End_k(k[G])$ be the regular representation.
It is easy to see that $P_\psi = det(x_{\sigma_i\sigma_j^{-1}})$.
So $P_\psi = \Pi_k P_{\psi_k}$ where each $\psi_k$ is an irreducible component of $\psi$.